# Rails 3 create with nested attributes for a polymorphic model failing with AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have a User model with polymorphic associations to an Address model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :addresses, :billing_addresses, :shipping_addresses, :shipping_same_as_billing

  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :billing_addresses, class_name: Address,  conditions: ['type = ?', :billing]
  has_many :shipping_addresses, class_name: Address,  conditions: ['type = ?', :shipping]
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
#...
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, polymorphic: true
  validates_presence_of :line1, :city, :state, :zip
  attr_accessible :line1, :line2, :city, :state, :zip, :type
#...
end
```

my form: (the interesting parts are the address blocks)

```
  = form_tag '/subscriptions', class: 'form-horizontal', id: "new_order" do |f|
    -if current_user.andand.stripe_customer_id.blank?
      = field_set_tag("Billing Information") do
        =simple_fields_for :creditcard do |cc|
          = cc.input :card_number, hint: "test cc: 4242424242424242", :wrapper => :append do
            = cc.input_field :card_number, id: "card_number", class: "input-medium",
                      size: 20, name: ""
            %div#cc_type_holder.cc_32.add-on{style:"position:absolute;width:35px"}
              %div#cc_type.cc_32
          = cc.input :cvc, input_html: { id: "cvc", class: "input-mini",
            size: 4, name: ""}, label: "CVC", hint: "This 3 or 4-digit code is usually found on the back of your credit card"
          = cc.input :expiration, as: :date,  start_year: Date.today.year,
            end_year: Date.today.year + 10, discard_day: true,
            order: [:month, :year], input_html: { class: "input-medium", name: ""}
        = simple_fields_for "user[billing_addresses]" do |billing_address|
          = billing_address.hidden_field :type, input_html: { value: "billing"}
          = billing_address.input :line1, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = billing_address.input :line2, required: false, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = billing_address.input :city, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = billing_address.input :state, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = billing_address.input :zip, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
    -if current_user.blank?
      = field_set_tag("User Information") do
        = simple_fields_for :user do |users_post|
          = users_post.input :email, input_html: { value: session[:email], type: "email",
            placeholder: 'user@domain.com', class: "input-medium" }
          = users_post.input :password, input_html: { class: "input-medium" }
    = field_set_tag("Shipping Information") do
      = simple_fields_for "user[shipping_addresses]" do |shipping_address|
        = shipping_address.input :shipping_same_as_billing, as: :boolean, input_html: {checked: true, id: 'shipping-same-as-billing'}
        %div#shipping-form
          = shipping_address.hidden_field :type, input_html: { value: "shipping"}
          = shipping_address.input :line1, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = shipping_address.input :line2, required: false, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = shipping_address.input :city, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = shipping_address.input :state, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}
          = shipping_address.input :zip, input_html: { class: "input-medium"}

      #stripe_error
      .form-actions
        = submit_tag t(".subscription.submit"), class: 'btn btn-success'
```

When I post the form I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Address(#70101930814600)
>   expected, got Array(#70101927961780)):

I read another post on Stack that mentioned trying to change

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

That didn't make any changes, I get the same error. I really don't want to build the associations manually. It seems like ActiveRecord can handle this and I am just missing something.

--edited for comment below

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HigNtHH08ER1S6p3xMUPlreWMuHngjo5S8z74jeqsO0=", "creditcard"=>{"expiration(3i)"=>"1"}, "user"=>{"billing_addresses"=>{"type"=>"", "line1"=>"1653 Main", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"Redwood City", "state"=>"California", "zip"=>"94061"}, "email"=>"tom@tom.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "shipping_addresses"=>{"shipping_same_as_billing"=>"0", "type"=>"", "line1"=>"1653 Main", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"Redwood City", "state"=>"California", "zip"=>"94061"}}, "stripeToken"=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

These are the params I am sending. I am just debugging in the controller right now with:

```
Rails.logger.debug params['user']['billing_addresses']
Rails.logger.debug params['user']['shipping_addresses']
u = User.new(params["user"])
Rails.logger.debug u

{"type"=>"", "line1"=>"1653 Main", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"Redwood City", "state"=>"California", "zip"=>"94061"}
{"shipping_same_as_billing"=>"0", "type"=>"", "line1"=>"1653 Main", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"Redwood City", "state"=>"California", "zip"=>"94061"}
```

I don't see where the array is coming from now. Unless ActiveRecord is taking the `shipping_addresses` and `billing_addresses` and treating them as an array of addresses...

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer and take a read and the link I've also provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your model user needs to an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` so try adding the following to your `user.rb`

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_addresses
```

Further to this, the error your getting:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Address(#70101930814600) expected, got Array(#70101927961780))

This is error is usually raised when the object assigned is given the incorrect type. So breaking down this error down. It seems that your object `Address` got the wrong type but **got** an Array. Somewhere your feeding an array when it you shouldn't.

Another key note: The polymorphic associations work by using a type column in addiiton to a foriegn key to specify the associated record. You need a column that you can specify it to. So an example would be for you to have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :addresses, :billing_addresses, :shipping_addresses,   
     :shipping_same_as_billing

      #Before       
      #has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy

      #After
      has_many :addresses, :as => user, dependent => :destroy

   end
```

Further reading: [Polymorphic Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Thanks David. I ended up refactoring the whole functionality into something simpler.